# Retrieving Array with dictionary for a particular key in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am facing problem in retrieving array which has dictionary for 6 keys.
when i put log to array..it prints

```
"<+25.51695000, +84.53490000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/19/11 12:10:43 PM India Standard Time",
```

I want to retrieve only `+25.51695000, +84.53490000` coordinates. How can I do so.

Comment: every time data like above format only or different

Comment: Post code for to get better idea.

Comment: @iApple:code would be very lenghty..

Comment: @:Narayana: ya, every time data will be in the same format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing by the NSLog (?) output, what you have in your NSArray are not NSDictionary elements, but a bunch of CLLocation elements.

You can have a look at the documentation here:

[CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126)

Essentially, you would do this:

```
CLLocation *location = (CLLocation *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
a = location.coordinate.latitude;
b = location.coordinate.longitude;
```

Comment: You will also need to add CoreLocation framework to your project and import a header:

#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>